# Can I reference a function within a function that is in parent space?

Tags: javascript

My function is not behaving as expected and I'm trying to determine if it's because I have a misunderstanding of scope.

The function below searches through an array called `dataLayer` to see if any of the objects have a `eventAction` property matching a string.

The idea is that if I cannot find a matching value, then push a value into `dataLayer` array, else do nothing.

I have a function that references another function. `getNegativeErrs()` references `getByValue()`.

What would the appropriate way of getting it to work be? How can I make `getByValue()` available to other functions?

Code:

```
  var errors = [
    'Your password must be at least 6 characters long.',
    'Please enter a valid email address.'
  ];

  getNegativeErrs(errors);

  function getNegativeErrs(ers) {
    for( i in errors ) {
      var errobj = getByValue(dataLayer, errors[i]); //updated based on comments
      if(!errobj) { // if errobj is undefined continue. errobj is undefined when it should have a value so getByValue() not working as expected
        dataLayer.push({
          'event': 'negative_errors',
          'unseen': errors[i]
        })
      }
    }
  }

  function getByValue(arr, value) {
    for (var j=0, jLen=arr.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      if (arr[j].eventAction == value) return arr[j];
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't see any scope issue. What makes you think there is one? Are these functions in different files? Or different scripts in the same file?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe there's something else wrong with it. When I create circumstances where errobj should have a value (an object) the console is showing it as undefined. So getByValue() is not working as expected. Thing is, it does work when I test in the console outside of the function. :-/

Comment: If this is all of your code, you are missing the `dataLayer` variable, so the function will not run correctly.

Comment: Well, one issue may be that you're passing `i`, the index, as the second argument to `getByValue`. Did you mean `getByValue(datayLayer, errors[i])`?

Comment: If so, you could just use the `.find()` method. `var errobj = dataLayer.find(function(data) { return data.eventAction === errors[i] })`

Comment: Shouldn't `if(!errobj)` be inverted? `if(errobj)` if you only want to add the errors if found?

Comment: @Ultimater not so, want to fire when the messages are NOT seen. Anyway, this question has evolved beyond the original title. Tried to delete in order to repost. Thanks for the helpful advice to all who responded

Answer (score 3):

Is the second argument to `getByValue` supposed to be a string or an integer? Currently it is an integer, which is the index of the `errors` array that you loop over. Your loop is invoking `getByValue` like this:

```
getByValue(dataLayer, 0)
getByValue(dataLayer, 1)
```

If you mean to pass in the value and not the index, change `getByValue(dataLayer, i)` to `getByValue(dataLayer, errors[i])`.

Comment: Yes, that is another mistake in my code thanks for pointing out. My original issue remains though. Will post a link in amoment

Answer (score 0):

If that is the extent of your code, `getByValue()` is in the global scope and should be accessible.

If this is it, it looks like this might not be working because `dataLayers` is not defined.

http://jsbin.com/bivepitafe/

Also, note that `getNegativeErrors()` is not using the `ers` parameter passed to it, but the `errors` variable that is also in the global scope.

```
function getNegativeErrs(ers) {
     for( i in errors ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem with the function getNegativeErrs, you are not using the argument that you passed into it.  it should look like this

```
function getNegativeErrs(ers) {
      for( i in ers ) {
  var errobj = getByValue(dataLayer, ers[i]); //updated based on comments
  if(!errobj) { // if errobj is undefined continue. errobj is undefined when it should have a value so getByValue() not working as expected
    dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'negative_errors',
      'unseen': ers[i]
    });
   }
  }
 }
```

Also, you are checking the `dataLayer` array for errors matching the key `eventAction` but then in the above function you are adding the key `event`... either one will work, you just need to make them the same.
I don't see an issue of scope though.  If you want to completely rule that out though, just cut and paste the `getByValue` function above the `getNegativeErrs` function.